# How can I code numerous MIN functions into one LINQ to DataSet query

Tags: c#, linq, oracle, linq-to-dataset

Ok, I've been working on this one for a while before asking for assistance. I have 4 Oracle based SQL queries which follow one another to deliver the requested data. I'm working in .NET and I think (I hope) I could use LINQ to DataSet to pass the first query along to the second, which passes to the third, and finally to the fourth. Where I'm running into a headache is with passing from the first to the second. I can get the first query into a DataSet through normal ODP.NET and C# queries.

Here is step 2

```
SELECT eid,
num_1,
MIN(cdts) keep (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY eid) first_creation,
cpers,
curent,
ag_id,
beat,
group_priority,
disp_date,
MIN(disp_time) keep (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY eid) first_call,
curent_16,
MIN(ad_sec) keep (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY eid) first_entry,
MIN(ds_sec) keep (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY eid) first_dispatched,
MIN(ar_sec) keep (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY eid) first_arrival,
MIN(csec) keep (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY unid) fastest_unit,
MIN(hold_sec) keep (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY eid) fastest_dispatch,
MIN(drive_sec) keep (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY unid) fastest_enroute,
MIN(resp_sec) keep (dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY unid) fastest_arrival,
unid FROM JC5A_STEP1 GROUP BY eid,
num_1,
cpers,
curent,
ag_id,
beat,
group_priority,
disp_date,
curent_16,
unid HAVING cpers <> 0 AND curent = 'T' AND curent_16 ='T' ORDER BY eid;
```

I've been trying to write a LINQ to DataSet which will populate this into a DataSet of its own. 
This is what I have so far and I know I'm way off

```
var query2 = (from row in query1.AsEnumerable() where row.Field<int32>("cpers") != 0 && row.Field<string>("curent") == "T" && row.Field<string>("curent_16") == "T" order by row.Field<Int32>("eid") select new { eid = row.Field<Int32>("eid"), ... }).Min(x => x.cdts);
```

I omitted all of the non-min fields and the one which is included for brevity. So, my question is, can I write a LINQ to DataSet query which will encompass what I have in the SELECT statement, and if so, where am I off my rails? If not, will I need to develop all of this in PL/SQL functions and call them from the application as Stored Procedures?

Thanks to everyone for any assistance,

T.

Based on a quick feedback, the first query is here:

```
select a.eid, a.num_1, e.cdts, e.cpers, a.curent, a.tycod, a.ag_id, a.lev3 as beat, case when a.priority < '2' then 'high' when a.priority > '2' then 'low' else 'normal' end as group_priority, substr(e.cdts,5,2)||'/'||substr(e.cdts,7,2)||'/'||substr(e.cdts,1,4) as disp_date, substr(e.cdts,9,6) as disp_time, e.curent AS curent_16, a.ad_sec, a.ds_sec, a.ar_sec, u.csec, a.ds_sec - a.ad_sec as hold_sec, u.csec - a.ds_sec as drive_sec, u.csec - a.ad_sec as resp_sec, a.priority, u.unid from un_hi u join (aeven a join event e on a.eid = e.eid) on u.eid = a.eid where e.cdts between '20110101' and '20110201' and a.tycod not in ('ANIMAL', 'BUSINESS', 'CARCHECK', 'CARSTAT', 'CIVSERV', 'CKLIGHTS', 'COURT', 'ERRAND', 'FOLLOW', 'FOOTPURS', 'GREATMAL', 'HOUSE', 'INFO', 'K9', 'PEDCHECK', 'PRISONER', 'RESIDENC', 'SELF', 'SPECIAL', 'STATION', 'TELEPHON', 'TRAFFIC', 'TRASH', 'WARRANT', 'WEATHER') and u.unit_status = 'AR' and a.ag_id = 'JCSO' and a.lev3 = 'JC5' and a.ar_sec is not null and a.ds_sec is not null and a.ds_sec - a.ad_sec between 1 and 7200 and a.ar_sec - a.ds_sec between 1 and 18000 and a.ar_sec - a.ad_sec between 1 and 18000 and u.csec - a.ds_sec > 1 and u.csec - a.ad_sec > 2 order by e.cpers, a.eid, u.csec;
```

Comment: You don't have any information about the first query, or what is used from that first query when calling the second query. Without that information, it is very difficult to answer the question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to overload this, but the first query is now added above. When I tried to add it in here, it was too many characters.

Comment: are you trying to union the results?

Comment: No. I'm trying to pare them down so funneling the results into a smaller and more specific set. The first query unions the three tables, but afterwards, each query can work off of the dataset from the preceding query. (I developed these as views against the database originally.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into using linq to sql for your problem instead of linq to datasets. Instead of writing your query in sql you can do it using c# directly which could afford you more options (custom objects) without the limitation and headache of dealing with the DataSet and friends.

Comment: I ended up using a sql query starting with a WITH clause and found that was more efficient. However, I did use LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entity for follow up queries quite nicely.